# android phonegap framework, best php framework for phonegap

Tags: php, cordova

it's the first time for me make android app with `Phonegap +Mysql + PHP` , so i hope you give me advice about what is the best `php` framework for `phonegap` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that phonegap is a client side technology and PHP is server side. PhoneGap app only communicates with server for example with restful web services. From a client side, it does not matter what php technology you use, as long as you send data with "understandable way" (eg. JSON).

**I think that question you would like to ask is: what is the best php framework for making web services.**